# How to draw image pointed towards specific x and y coordinates in Canvas HTML

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So I know the coordinates of the tip of my image. Now, I want to rotate my image so that the tip is pointed towards some x and y coordinates. So how would I go about doing this? would I have to change the parameters in this `drawImage` method? Or is there a method in javascript canvas to somehow rotate my image?

Answer (score 0):

Use [rotate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/rotate) to transform the coordinate system, draw your image, then reset the transform.

```js
// utility to convert degress to radians
const d2r = d => d * Math.PI / 180;

// get the 2d context
const ctx = document.getElementById('c').getContext('2d');

// move origin to the point around which to rotate
ctx.translate(100, 100);

// rotate coordinate system 45°
ctx.rotate(d2r(45));

// draw whatever you need to draw
ctx.fillRect(-10, -10, 20, 20);

// reset the coordinate system
ctx.restore();
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the law of cosines to find the angle, here is a function that makes use of that. (This is a trigonometry course, here is an interactive [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gb3mnb4v2a) to demonstrate it.)

```
function drawImageAt(image, x, y, scale, rads) {
  var width = image.width;
  var height = image.height;

  ctx.translate(x, y);
  ctx.rotate(rads);
  ctx.drawImage(
    image,
    (-width * scale) / 2,
    (-height * scale) / 2,
    width * scale,
    height * scale
  );
  ctx.rotate(-rads);
  ctx.translate(-x, -y);
}

// (x1,y1) is the current position and (x2,y2) is the target position
function pointAt(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  let a = x1 - x2;
  let b = y1 - y2;
  let c = Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b);
  let radians = Math.acos((b * b - (a * a + c * c)) / (-2 * a * c));

  // Special Cases
  if (a === 0) {
    radians = Math.PI / 2;
  }
  if (b < 0) {
    return 2 * Math.PI - radians;
  }

  return radians;
}
```

I coded a quick [demo](https://tlbxe1.csb.app/) if you wanna take a look

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?